# Is there a good line profiler for ruby?

Tags: ruby, profiling

I need to get a process time for each line in ruby script, but couldn't find any suitable gem.

I often use [line_profiler](https://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/#line-profiler) in python and it's really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try [rblineprof](https://github.com/tmm1/rblineprof) and [ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof).

Comment: Thak you. rblineprof gem is fine. In OSX, I couldn't install original gem, so used this:
https://github.com/MasterLambaster/PLine