# line by line profiler in Ruby

Tags: ruby, line-profiler

For a quick overview of code, line profilers are very good. Python has very good line profiler. Searching gave some [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420924/is-there-a-good-line-profiler-for-ruby) but this post is very old the packages mentioned here have not been maintained. `ruby-prof` and Ruby's `benchmark` are good but I don't see any line-by-line profiling results.

Is there any good line profiler that can profile Ruby code and methods?

Comment: please specify reasons in comments before voting to close. it will help me and also the community as a whole.

Comment: I've recently been using [`rblineprof`](https://github.com/tmm1/rblineprof) which does the trick